# Chrome/Safari/WebKit (and IE?): Overflow not being respected

Tags: html, css, webkit, overflow

Can anyone tell me why the menu at http://preview.endlesscircle.org/ expands by about 5px horizontally only in WebKit and Trident (IE) when you click the menu on "Parent Education" to view that page (but not FireFox)?

(Oddly enough, in Chrome, when you have the Developer Tools window open in the same window as the web page--open as a panel, the issue disappears.)

It's the only page in WebKit where the menu width expands, and in IE, it expands on that page and "Community Involvement."

The CSS for #body is:

```
#body
{
    margin-top:208px;
    position:absolute;
    width:925px;
    padding:0 20px 0 20px;
    overflow:hidden;
    overflow-y:visible;
}
```

How come in WebKit and IE the horizontal overflow is not hidden? For the life of me, I just cannot figure this one out!

Comment: I'm not seeing the menu expand. I do, however, see the whole page shift by about 5px between the two pages. This could be because one of your containers are expanding...

Comment: @Jesse: Not seeing this behavior. Could be because the Education page has a scrollbar which shifts the center of the page slightly left.

@Agile: Can't reproduce on Chrome/Win7. Looks fine here.

Comment: @Matthew : You're right, silly me.

Comment: I don't see the shift in any browser. (FF, Chrome, Safari) But I DO see the entire page break completely in IE 7 due to a javascript bug.

Comment: The only difference i see between the two pages is the menu bar actually shrinks slightly due to the appearance of the scroll bars.. ?   (although it only impacts the menu bar - the footer bar has the correct width...  - didnt look into why)

Answer (score 0):

In parent-education.css you're restating the width of body:

```
body 
{
    width:933px;
}
```

Take it out and Webkit should work fine now. I'm not able to test in IE7.